# Sacar el total de boleta y factura

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hola buenas debo sacar el total de factura y boleta de vendedores de la siguiente manera

```
    SELECT v.rutvendedor,
           COUNT(*)
    FROM vendedor v
    JOIN factura f ON v.rutvendedor=f.rutvendedor
    GROUP BY v.rutvendedor;
```

Esto me saca el siguiente resultado del total de cada rut de factura
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    SELECT v.rutvendedor,
           COUNT(*)
    FROM vendedor v
    JOIN boleta b ON v.rutvendedor=b.rutvendedor
    GROUP BY v.rutvendedor;
```

Este me da el total de boleta de cada rut

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora necesito que esas dos tablas queden en una consulta, intente de hacerlo de esta manera que es la unica que se me ocurrio pero me dio los siguientes datos

```
    SELECT v.rutvendedor,
           COUNT(f.numfactura),
           COUNT(b.numboleta)
    FROM vendedor v
    JOIN factura f ON v.rutvendedor=f.rutvendedor
    JOIN boleta b ON v.rutvendedor=b.rutvendedor
    GROUP BY v.rutvendedor;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y no logro sacarlo de ninguna manera esta es la BD:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La función `COUNT(*)` en cada consulta que columna de que tabla cuenta?

Comment: el primer count(f.total) es de factura y el segundo es de boleta @BetaM

Comment: @BetaM ps no entiendo osea deje la BD y necesito lograr juntar la primera tabla que cotiene el total de factura de vendedor que lo saque con un count(*) pero puedo sacarlo igual con un COUNT(numfactura) y los mismo con boleta, pero hacer eso en una solo query se me entiende?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al hacer el join lo datos se multiplican ya que se recogen todos los casos, para lo que quieres puedes contar distintos con `COUNT(DISTINCT campo)`.

Pongo un ejemplo basado en tu caso:
**Schema (PostgreSQL v12)**

```
CREATE TABLE vendedor (
  idvend INT
);
INSERT INTO vendedor (idvend) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO vendedor (idvend) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO vendedor (idvend) VALUES (3);

CREATE TABLE factura (
  idfact INT,
  idvend INT
);
INSERT INTO factura (idfact,idvend) VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO factura (idfact,idvend) VALUES (2,1);
INSERT INTO factura (idfact,idvend) VALUES (3,1);
INSERT INTO factura (idfact,idvend) VALUES (4,2);
INSERT INTO factura (idfact,idvend) VALUES (5,2);
INSERT INTO factura (idfact,idvend) VALUES (6,3);

CREATE TABLE boleta (
  idbol INT,
  idvend INT
);
INSERT INTO boleta (idbol,idvend) VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO boleta (idbol,idvend) VALUES (2,2);
INSERT INTO boleta (idbol,idvend) VALUES (3,2);
INSERT INTO boleta (idbol,idvend) VALUES (4,3);
INSERT INTO boleta (idbol,idvend) VALUES (5,3);
INSERT INTO boleta (idbol,idvend) VALUES (6,3);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT v.idvend,
           COUNT(*)
    FROM vendedor v
    JOIN factura f ON v.idvend=f.idvend
    GROUP BY v.idvend;

| idvend | count |
| ------ | ----- |
| 1      | 3     |
| 2      | 2     |
| 3      | 1     |
```

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT v.idvend,
           COUNT(*)
    FROM vendedor v
    JOIN boleta b ON v.idvend=b.idvend
    GROUP BY v.idvend;

| idvend | count |
| ------ | ----- |
| 1      | 1     |
| 2      | 2     |
| 3      | 3     |
```

---

**Query #3**

```
SELECT v.idvend,
           COUNT(DISTINCT idfact) AS facturas, COUNT(DISTINCT idbol) as boletas
    FROM vendedor v
    INNER JOIN factura f ON v.idvend=f.idvend
    INNER JOIN boleta b ON v.idvend=b.idvend
    GROUP BY v.idvend;

| idvend | facturas | boletas |
| ------ | -------- | ------- |
| 1      | 3        | 1       |
| 2      | 2        | 2       |
| 3      | 1        | 3       |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: Muchas gracias man de verdad estoy muy agradecido, me funciono